# A mechanical switch current/voltage rating

Tags: power-electronics

I have a mechanical switch, and it has been rated 5A at 125V, and 3A at 230V.
I think it is not because of power, because 5*125 is not equals 3*230. Why does the current rating change depending on voltage?

Both ratings are for AC

Comment: higher voltage more like damaged by arcing

Comment: It also changes (drastically) when you change from AC to DC.  DC arcs stay longer than AC arcs.

Comment: 5*125==625 while 3*230==690. This is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a mechanical switch is turned off the contacts separate, but the current tries to keep going (as an arc) until the gap is too large - then the current stops. The higher the current you're switching and the higher the circuit voltage, both will tend to keep the arc going for longer. So for a particular switch you can balance voltage and current ( as in your example ) - lower voltage lets you use higher current and vice versa.

If we assume the above is AC then you may also notice that the DC rated current for a particular switch is lower than the AC rated current - this is also due to how switching arcs develop. In AC the current drops through zero 100 or 120 times a second which helps the current to turn off, but DC doesn't have this 'help' and so the current rating for DC has to be lower.